# MySQL date criteria with parameters do not work

Tags: python, mysql, web2py, string-interpolation

I execute a MySQL query in Python.
When I execute the query without parameters, it works perfectly:

```
rows = db.executesql("""SELECT
                profile_id, date_stamp,
                COUNT(amount), SUM(amount)
                FROM amount_table
                WHERE (
                    date_stamp > '2017-01-01'
                    AND
                    date_stamp <= '2017-07-26'
                    )
                GROUP BY
                  profile_id, date_stamp;""")
```

However, when I execute the same query with parameters, it just ignores the date criteria and brings results from all dates including 2017-07-27:

```
rows = db.executesql("""SELECT
                profile_id, date_stamp,
                COUNT(amount), SUM(amount)
                FROM amount_table
                WHERE (
                    date_stamp > %s
                    AND
                    date_stamp <= %s
                    )
                GROUP BY
                  profile_id, date_stamp;""", (the_begin_date, the_end_date))
```

Here,

```
the_begin_date = {date} 2017-01-01

the_end_date = {date} 2017-07-26
```

I couldn't figure out why this happens. Any ideas?

PS: I am using web2py DAL class to execute queries.

Comment: Add quotes or better use Prepared Statements

Comment: Adding quotes does not work

Comment: Are you sure you're calling `executesql` correctly? Most Python DB drivers accept `%s` as a placeholder and can bind data to it, but this might require transforming your dates into [ISO-8601 format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) of `YYYY-MM-DD` like you had in the original working example.

Comment: Are you passing in date objects? Have you tried creating your own connection directly via the MySQL Python driver and passing those same arguments to the driver's `.execute()` method (ultimately, that is what the DAL ends up doing)?

Comment: Hi Anthony, when I execute using `.execute()` method of MySQL Python driver, it works. 
DAL's `db._adapter.cursor._last_executed` has missing dates: `SELECT
                    profile_id, date_stamp,
                    COUNT(donation_amount), SUM(donation_amount)
                    FROM donation_table
                    WHERE (
                        date_stamp > '
                        AND
                        date_stamp <= '
                        )
                    GROUP BY
                      profile_id, date_stamp;`